# Set angular component default values

Tags: angular-material, angular6, angular-components

I am using angular material components. In `mat-card-actions` component I would like to set `align=end` as a default value, so that I do not need to add it in all my forms.

What is the best way to achieve this? I was thinking about extending the component, but I'm hoping for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it by simple style in your css. Look :
In your global styles or some else define this styles:

```
mat-card-actions {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

[Example on stack](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kndbxp?file=app/card-fancy-example.css)

**P.S.**  It is same as use align="end" but you make it by CSS not by JS